# SharePoint Online Lookup Column lagging

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, lookup-column

[image: SharePoint Online Lookup Column lagging]

It started about a week ago, and it only has about 50 items. what is the best approach to tackle this.

Thank you in advances.

Comment: Open a ticket with Microsoft, if they have any best approach recommendation about look up with quick edit...

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia Will do! Thank you